# Deveria reabrir esta resposta como Community Wiki?

Tags: debate

[Esta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/7261) teve uma boa resposta do @talles, mas que ele acabou deletando por causa de pequenos erros apontados por outros usuários. Ao invés de corrigir, ele preferiu deletar.

Algo que nós podemos fazer é copiar o conteúdo da resposta em outra resposta como Community Wiki, então esses erros poderiam ser corrigidos por quem se sentir a vontade.

O que acham?

Comment: Não acho correto "apropriar-se" de uma resposta. A melhor solução seria convencer o @talles a desfazer a exclusão. Ele não aceitou bem os pontos criticados, mas talvez depois de esfriar a cabeça ele pondere que vale mais a pena deixar a contribuição do que deixar o trabalho "perdido".

Comment: Acredito que quando um usuário exclui uma publicação dele por qualquer motivo que seja, ele está dizendo: *"**não quero** que isso seja publicado"*. Tomar a ação de publicar um texto contra a vontade do seu autor seria no mínimo errado.

Comment: Já foi conversado com o @Talles, (além dos comentários na própria questão) e ele optou por deixar a resposta removida. Se for a vontade dele, ele pode desfazer a exclusão a qualquer momento. E se fosse para qualquer um ajustar os pontos necessários, não se deveria tirar o mérito do autor com CW. E se alguém tiver algo a mais a dizer, pode postar separadamente como resposta propria.

Comment: OK, deixarei fechada.