# Significado do voto no META

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso, meta, votos

É bem sabido que o voto em uma resposta no meta representa **apenas** concordância ou discordância do que está sendo dito. É algo totalmente subjetivo, opinião de cada um.

Minha dúvida é, e quanto a perguntas?

Se um usuário levanta um questionamento e minha reação imediata é "não, isso não deve ser feito! sou contra!", é certo votar negativamente? Ou devo positivar por ter levantado um questionamento válido e útil?

Já havia acontecido antes, e o gatilho que me fez abrir essa pergunta foi [essa aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1666/deveria-reabrir-esta-resposta-como-community-wiki). Votei positivamente na pergunta, mas não quero que a pontuação positiva seja interpretada de outra forma.

Acho que seria muito bom ter o texto da tooltip modificado no meta para refletir isso. Muitos novatos devem se confundir e se sentir mal ao levar uma negativação por dar sua opinião. (pedido de recurso)

Comment: Muitas vezes eu voto a favor na questão para que ela chame mais atenção e não exatamente porque eu concordo. Nesse caso é um pouco confuso porque o título simplesmente faz uma pergunta enquanto o detalhamento faz uma proposta. Em situações assim eu acho que deveríamos colocar respostas contra ou a favor e deixar que os votos nessas respostas digam o resultado.

Comment: No MSO e no MSE foi combinado (bem, mais ou menos combinado) que só se usa votos contra para expressar discordância em pedidos de novo recurso (devidamente tagueadas). Nas demais, os downvotes teriam o sentido "normal".

Comment: Pra mim uma pergunta com -14 é tão interessante quanto uma com +14, no sentido de que há um *feedback* muito forte da comunidade. Enquanto a tooltip não vem, é legal dar um toque nos meta-novatos: "ô, este -14 não significa que sua pergunta é uma melda e que você tem que ir pro cantinho e morrer de vergonha".

Answer (score 7):

Até onde sei, por consenso já obtido em outros metas - deve-se votar positivamente na pergunta se você acha que o assunto é interessante e deve ser discutido, mesmo que não concorde com a proposta. Em seguida, você deve incluir uma resposta explicando porque é a favor ou contra a proposta.